# How to show date from db in input filed in html - django

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

My small project is in django. When I add new record to the db everything is OK. One of the input fields is for the date and have type 'date'

```
<input type="date" id="id_date_one" name="date_one" class=" form-control" required>
```

It is working... sending date to the db.
Problem is when I try to edit records again. In forms I see everything without this date.

```
<input type="date" id="id_date_one" name="date_one" class=" form-control" required value="{{obj.date_one}}">
```

input field is empty when type of this field is 'date', but if I change type for 'text' the date is presented in input field normally.

In db this column have type 'date' also.

My question is:
**Why when input field have type 'date' is empty during edition the records and how can I change it?**

Thanks for any sugestions

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the value there needs to be in the format that the HTML date input expects it. Using `{{ obj.date_one }}` is return a date type. You need to render it as the string value the [html input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) wants. You can use the `date` template filter to convert it to a string within the template.

That said, I'd highly recommend using a [Form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/) or [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/) to avoid handling this yourself.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I completely forgot about it. I need to change my mindset a bit and render forms. I should have more control over them. Anyway, it works and I solved the problem. Thanks again!